# GetCurrentDirectory() only retrieve disk name

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'v been doing some C++ programming I have stumbled on a weird behavior,
whenever I try to get current directory using GetCurrentDirectory() it gives me back only the letter of the current disk.

**Here's the code :**

```
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH + 1] = L"";
DWORD len = GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, path);

cout << (char *)path;
```

**Here's the output :**

```
Z
```

Because my project is in my Z:\ disk

I was wondering if it has to do with the buffer size but i set it to MAX_PATH and even tried to set it to 1024.

Comment: What is the expected output? In which directory do you run your program?

Comment: I tried to put it in my C:\ directory on the desktop and it retrieved only the C letter aswell, so full path is expected like C:\Users\XXX\Desktop

Comment: You compile your program in UNICODE mode. Use `wcout`  instead of `cout`. And don't use the `TCHAR` type but use `w_char` instead. Actually the `(char *)` cast is the culprit here. The `TCHAR` type is only useful if you want to compiler your code as UNICODE character set program or as Multibyte character set program, latter is obsolete by now.

Comment: Your output would be better readable if you just used copy&paste to include the plain text into the question. Your screenshot seems to have choped part of the text and mixed with text in another window.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I tried it and it only retrieve the letter of the disk aswell

Comment: Why are you tagging C when it's C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(char *)` cast in `cout << (char *)path` makes the compiler believe that `path` points to a `char`, but it actually points to a `wchar_t`.

You want this (uses the multibyte character version of GetCurrentDirectory (hence the **A** in GetCurrentDirectory):

```
char path[MAX_PATH + 1] = "";
DWORD len = GetCurrentDirectoryA(MAX_PATH, path);
cout << path;
```

or this (recommended):

```
wchar_t path[MAX_PATH + 1] = L"";
DWORD len = GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, path);
wcout << path;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, didnt knew there was a Multibyte version

Comment: @Quentin_otd just forget about `TCHAR` and other `_tstrlen`, `_T("foo")` etc. They only exist so you can compile your code as UNICODE or as multibyte program.

Comment: `w_char` should be `wchar_t`, or WinAPI `WCHAR`. Also, a `MAX_PATH` buffer suffices if long paths aren't enabled because `SetCurrentDirectory` is limited to `MAX_PATH - 1` characters, including the required trailing slash. However, you should still code defensively, in case long paths are enabled for the process or there's an error. Check that the return value is greater than zero and less than `MAX_PATH`.

Comment: @ErykSun thanks, I corrected the typo. And your remark concerning long paths is correct.